# Dual Time Machine setup: does it make sense at all

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have MacMini with 1 Tb Fusion Drive. About 800 Gb is used.

I have 5 Tb USB3 HDD connected to it specifically for Time Machine.

I also have ESXi server (connected via Wired Gigabit Ethernet to MacMini) in my setup which have OS X VMs and can (using Apple's macOS Server.app) serve as Time Machine target. I have about 1.4 Tb free space on one of server's HDDs (just regular consumer HDD, all 'important' VMs are on NAS with RAID1 anyway) which I can dedicate to make backup better. I arleady use it this VM as Time Machine target for my Macbook Air (separate disk to better manage space).

MacMini's Fusion Drive is ALSO being backed up by Carbon Copy Cloner on seprate local physical USB3 1 Tb HDD + ~/Documents are being backed up by Arq to Google Nearline).

Does it make sense to setup Time Machine target for MacMini in VM and use both 5 Tb HDD and VM's 1.4 Tb as targets for MacMini? I can't dedicate more space to it and I heard recommendations that Time Machine targets should always be at least 2x space which I can't do here.

Which issues I can encounter using this setup?